# DateTime to milliseconds from midnight

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

How can I convert the *time* part of a given `DATETIME` to the number of milliseconds since midnight? For instance,

```
'2011-08-29 00:00:00' -> 0
'2011-08-28 00:00:00' -> 0
'2011-08-29 01:00:00' -> 3600000
```

Is there any simple way to do this in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WITH Dates(D) AS
(
SELECT { ts '2011-08-29 00:00:00.000' } UNION ALL
SELECT { ts '2011-08-28 00:00:00.000' } UNION ALL
SELECT { ts '2011-08-29 01:00:00.000' }
)
SELECT  DATEDIFF(ms, 0,
                 DATEADD(Day, 0 - DATEDIFF(Day, 0, D), D))
FROM Dates
```

Comment: +1 Y'know, isn't it easier with SQL Server 2008 and date types?

Answer (score 3):

A bit less elegant - but self documenting?

```
select DATEPART(MILLISECOND,d)+1000*(DATEPART(SECOND,d)+60*(DATEPART(MINUTE,d)+60*DATEPART(HOUR,d)))
```

I think it also behaves differently around daylight savings - which may be good or bad depending on requirements.

Comment: I don't mind this version - but the 60 * Hours should be 3600 instead

Comment: No. It reads right-to-left. It converts hours to minutes, then adds that to minutes. Next, it converts that number to seconds and adds that to seconds. Next, it converts that number to milliseconds and adds it to the milliseconds.

Comment: +1; I preferred this approach but solved for seconds. I also wrote it left-to-right: `((DATEPART(HOUR, d)) * 60 + DATEPART(MINUTE, d)) * 60 + DATEPART(SECOND, d)`

Answer (score 0):

why not

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, convert(time,'2011-08-29 01:23:45.356'))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
It requires SQL Server 2008 or above but it can be easily adapted for versions that don't support the date & datetime2 datatypes.

```
DECLARE @Well datetime2(3) = '2023-02-07 00:00:00.123';
SELECT DATEDIFF(millisecond, CAST(@Well AS date), @Well);
```