# Calculate difference between time over midnight and condition

Tags: sql

When I calculate the difference between two time, I must also pay attention to what happens after midnight.

```
select * 
        ,datediff(second,
             cast([schedule_deptime]as time),
             cast([prev_announce_time]as time)) 
         as kpi1_delta
```

| id | date_event | schedule_deptime | prev_announce_time | kpi1_delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 79643204 | 2021-02-11 19:55:52.000 | 19:15 | 2021-02-11 19:39:01.000 | 1441 |
| 79569510 | 2021-02-11 16:51:05.000 | 16:50 | 2021-02-11 16:48:17.000 | -103 |
| 106160161 | 2021-01-21 20:43:44.000 | 20:28 | 2021-01-21 01:03:41.000 | -69859 |
| 106216877 | 2021-01-21 23:50:10.000 | 23:45 | 2021-01-21 00:06:52.000 | -85088 |
| 79703534 | 2021-02-11 23:58:01.000 | 00:04 | 2021-02-11 00:03:01.000 | -59 |

I should get for my third and fourth row:

| id | date_event | schedule_deptime | prev_announce_time | kpi1_delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 106160161 | 2021-01-21 20:43:44.000 | 20:28 | 2021-01-21 01:03:41.000 | 16541 |
| 106216877 | 2021-01-21 23:50:10.000 | 23:45 | 2021-01-21 00:06:52.000 | 1312 |

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Did you do any research on this? because this question seems to have the info you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228246/datetime-to-milliseconds-from-midnight (with a small adaptation)

Comment: You really need to treat `schedule_deptime` as a date/time value, not just a time value, so that differences across midnight (or delays of more than 24 hours) are handled correctly.  You also seem to have some oddities in your data that puzzle me.  For ID 106216977, the scheduled departure is 23:45 on the 21st; the previous announced time was apparently 00:06 on the 21st, some 23h 39m before the scheduled departure time.  There is not, self-evidently, any crossing of a midnight boundary there (should the previous announced time be on the 22nd?).  I'm puzzled about what should be happening.

Comment: thx ! you're right but that's unfortunately what extracts it  and I have two problems first schedule_deptime don't contain the date and into prev_announce_time the date must be one day more if the time is greater than schedule_deptime ex : schedule_deptime = 23:45 and  prev_announce_time = 00:06:52.000 in this case it should be 00:06:52 - 23:35:00

Comment: There are similar issues with ID 106160161 too.

Comment: The departure time is associated with a date — your database simply doesn't record it explicitly.  My primary recommendation would be to convert scheduled departure time into a full date/time value stored explicitly in the database.  It would make your calculations trivial, and is more accurate.  Sure, you would often display only the time of day part when the date can be inferred accurately, but storing the data accurately makes life easier.  It also removes guesswork from the system.

Comment: Thx Jonathan ! In fact, 'schedule_deptime' is taken from a dump. Unfortunately, there is only the scheduled departure time. Each event is recorded: the display of announcements. In the table, the date_event is the actual departure, the schedule_deptime, and the prev_announce_time is the time of a display before departure and taken from a previous line. So I have to calculate the delta between the moment of posting and the planned departure. Indeed, I think there is a date error but that's what I have. I thought to subtract 86400 sec or even add a day if the schedule time is before midnight